# Brand new S4 randomly restarting

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, reboot, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Is there any known reason why my 5 day old S4 would be randomly restarting? It doesn't appear to be a heat problem, its usually around 33 degrees (celcius) and more often than not, its idle. I only know its restarted because I hear the startup tone in my pocket.

I'm not sure how to even begin to troubleshoot this.

Thanks,

Christian

Comment: Depends on what you did to it within those 5 days: rooted? any apps installed? custom ROM flashed? Does that also happen after a factory-reset, without any additional apps installed?

Comment: Not a great deal done to it, no rooting, no custom roms. No big apps (or, many apps) installed. Nova, SwiftKey a bunch of social apps.. The biggest app is probably Real Racing 3 but the problem was occuring before that. I don't know how to factory reset, but I'm assuming it'll wipe everything?

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't root or install any custom Rom, this leaves one the apps you've installed as a possible cause. If you contacted Samsung support, they probably would recommend a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) to rule out software issues as well, so this is a working approach.

Yes, a factory-reset would delete all data and the apps you've installed. You might wish to take a look at our [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) and its [most frequented questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/factory-reset?sort=frequent) for details. If a factory-reset indeed solves your issue, start re-installing your apps one-by-one with enough time to check in between.

See also our [backup](/questions/tagged/backup)[tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) for hints on how to save your data. [Helium - App Sync and Backup](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.koushikdutta.backup) might come in handy here, as it allows you to backup apps and their data, and even restore them separately (one-by-one) in an easy way.

Of course, if you can live with the current state a little longer, you might want to wait for alternative answers first, so maybe a factory-reset is avoidable after all. If you want to use this approach, you find an appropriate item in your device's settings, as well as in the recovery menu. Again, you'll find more dtails via the mentioned tag-wiki.